# Fedora 22 - Failed to restart httpd.service: Access denied

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd

I want to start web development and I was trying to install LAMP. I installed Apache using this [tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/comment-page-2/) but the command they give to start the apache server fails:

> systemctl start httpd.service

returns

> Failed to restart httpd.service: Access denied

I googled it and couldn't find any solution, I'm stuck here. What can I do?

Comment: Are you running as root? Are any relevant logs (perhaps look inside `/var/log`) show anything?

Comment: Relevant logs would come from `journalctl`, probably. Maybe `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=httpd.service`. But it really sounds like you're not running that as root, does `sudo systemctl start httpd.service` work?

Comment: I reinstalled Apache and it's fixed after a reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution, it seems there is a [bug](https://major.io/2015/09/18/systemd-in-fedora-22-failed-to-restart-service-access-denied/) in Fedora 22 that keeps the system from starting and restarting services.

You have to re-execute systemd using

`systemctl daemon-reexec`

After that I was able to start the service.

This solution works on Cent OS 7 as well.